# alignParentRight in xml not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-xml

I have a generic layout, to which I attach fragments:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="@drawable/back"
     android:orientation="vertical" >

<include 
    android:id = "@+id/login_header"
    layout="@layout/header_layout"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I have a fragment which I want to display on the right side of the screen.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="@dimen/two_third_width"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/small_margin"
android:background="@drawable/stock_price_bg"
tools:context=".FoundItemFragment" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

The layout is displayed left-justified rather than right justified.   When I color the fragment_container FrameLayout, I see that it takes the entire width of the screen. I attach the fragment with the following code in my  "FoundItemFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener" class:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View fragView = null;
    try {
        fragView = inflater.inflate(layoutID, container, false);
        //LoadData(fragView);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return fragView;
}
```

The container parameter passed to this routine has the id of the fragment_container layout, so I am not attaching it to some other object which might have settings that override the alignParentRight setting.  Why is the fragment displayed left-justified rather than right-justified?

Comment: make `fragment_container` align to the right, as it seems your fragment layout will place under `fragment_container`. You can align it either by using `WeightSum` property or make the parent of `FrameLayout` as Relative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The layout parent should be `Relative Layout` so that `alignParentRight` will work .

You are using the `alignParentRight` for a root element `RelativeLayout`

Answer (score 1):

Just edit your container xml to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="@drawable/back" >

<include 
    android:id = "@+id/login_header"
    layout="@layout/header_layout"
    android:layout_alignParentTop = "true"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:below = "@id/login_header"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: it depends on the container, if the container is the `RelativeLayout` so your code will work , but if the container layout is the `@+id/fragment_container` ( which is a `FrameLayout`) so your code will not work , the `FrameLayout` is the one which sould be changed to a `RelativeLayout`. and if you have added the attribute `alignParentRight` to the `FrameLayout`, so you should change the `layout_width` to something different of `match_parent` :).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="@drawable/back"
     android:orientation="vertical" >

<include 
    android:id = "@+id/login_header"
    layout="@layout/header_layout"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Since `generic` layout hold the container of the fragment, you should align/place the fragment there.
Placement of the views of the fragment should be done in fragment specific xml file

Comment: The FrameLayout spans the width of the screen.  Some of the fragments I attach are right aligned, some are left align, so the alignment must be in the fragment layout.

Comment: Since the behavior of frameLayout is supposed to change at runtime, so you can set the alignment parameter of framelayout at runtime using java code. You can adjust the alignment of framelayout just before assigning the fragment to the layout.